# If $R$ is a rng, show that $R\times \mathbb{Z}$ contains a subset in one to one correspondence with $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a rng (satisfies all the axioms of a ring except multiplicative identity). Define addition and multiplication in $R\times\mathbb{Z}$ by: $(a,n)+(b,m)=(a+b,n+m)$ and $(a,n)\cdot(b,m)=(ab+ma+nb,nm)$. Show that $(R\times \mathbb{Z},+,\cdot)$ is a ring that contains a subset in one-to-one correspondence with $R$ that has all the properties of the algebraic object $(R,+,\cdot)$.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. What are your thoughts on the problem, and what have you tried? Please give a brief summary of this so that people can give help that's *relevant* to you.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative

Comment: R is not necessarily commutative.

Answer (score 1):

This process adjoins an identity to a ring that may or may not have an identity, called a rng or a pseudo-ring.  See if you can check that $(0,1)$ is a multiplicative identity in the ring $R\times \mathbb{Z}$ under the operation you've stated, and also that:

$$\varphi:R\hookrightarrow R\times \mathbb{Z}\\r\longmapsto (r,0)$$

is an injection of pseudo-rings.  This means that the map respects addition and multiplication.  I'll check addition, and leave multiplication for you:

$$\varphi(r+s)=(r+s,0)=(r,0)+(s,0)=\varphi(r)+\varphi(s)\qquad\checkmark$$

Comment: I am still a bit confused. I can check that $(0,1)$ is a multiplicative identity, but I am not sure what the next part means. Thank you

Comment: @user89854: I've added a bit more to the answer for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot more sense to me!